# Weird histogram result from cv2

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, histogram

So, I grabbed some sample code for generating and plotting a color histogram off here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/22/clever-girl-a-guide-to-utilizing-color-histograms-for-computer-vision-and-image-search-engines/

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2, os, glob

os.chdir(r"....pathname....")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    chans = cv2.split(image)
    colors = ("b", "g", "r")
    plt.figure()
    plt.title("'Flattened' Color Histogram")
    plt.xlabel("Bins")
    plt.ylabel("# of Pixels")

    for (chan, color) in zip(chans, colors):
        hist = cv2.calcHist([chan], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
        cv2.normalize(hist,hist,8,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        plt.plot(hist, color = color)
        plt.xlim([0,256])
    plt.savefig(file + '_hist.jpg')
```

And for most images, I get a decent looking histogram like this for example:[image]

However for some images, I get a basically flat histogram with the end going to "extreme" values, like this:
[image]

Here is the original image, which produced the latter histogram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA9ZR.jpg

Can anyone explain what is happening and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your code using numpy to make sure it wasn't cv2 that was doing something wrong. Although it may look unusual the results are actually consistent with the image.

Firstly, take a look at the image intensity (pixel values) in each channel:[image]

You can see the flowers have a very high value in the blue channel (close to 255), and the background has a very high value in the red channel. Not very many pixels have a high value in the green channel.

Computing the histogram of pixel valuesfor each channel I get the same result:[image]

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = np.array(Image.open('im.jpg'))
channelNames=['R','G','B']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(10,4))
for channel, ax in enumerate(axes):
    imshow=ax.imshow(im.T[channel].T, cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=255)
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    ax.set_title(channelNames[channel])

fig.colorbar(imshow,fraction=0.06, pad=0.07, shrink=1.5)
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.9)
fig.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6,4))
for channel in range(3):
    cts = np.bincount(im.T[channel].flatten())
    bins=np.arange(0,256,1)
    ax.plot(bins, cts, c=channelNames[channel])
ax.set_xlabel('Bins')
ax.set_ylabel('# of Pixels')
fig.show()
```